# Preventing duplicate records on the same/between date interval. Error: Schema.SObjectField for column of type Date

Tags: apex, trigger

I have an object that receive data from users that are either in sick-leave or holidays named HR. What I need to do it to prevent that an manager log a duplicated record on the same day or on the interval.

For example, an driver cannot have an sick-leave and holidays within the same date interval. For exemple if he is on sick-leave from 01/09 to 05/09 you cannot log an holiday on the 03/09.

Can someone help to think in the best solution? Will attached the code that I'm using.

QUESTION: What is the best way to check interval between dates? Already tried but always receive this error.

```
    trigger HrDuplicates on hr__c (before insert, before update) {

        List<hr__c> personnel = [
        SELECT Id,date_end__c,date_start__c FROM hr__c
        WHERE status__c = 'approved'
        AND
        date_start__c >=: hr__c.date_start__c AND date_end__c <= :hr__c.date_end__c
        AND
        Id IN :Trigger.New ];


 if(trigger.isInsert){
        if(personnel.size()!= 0){
            h.addError('There is already another HR record in between time frame');
        }
    }
    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
            hr__c hOld = Trigger.oldMap.get(h.Id);
            if ((h.personnel__c != hOld.personnel__c || h.date_start__c != hOld.date_start__c ||h.date_end__c != hOld.date_end__c ) && personnel.size()!= 0) {
                h.addError('There is already another HR record in between time frame');
            }
        }
}
```

The error that I got is "Invalid bind expression type of Schema.SObjectField for column of type Date at line 3 column 33    ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a step back...You shouldn't be doing any real logic in the trigger. Imagine if you have to add functionality to this object and you risk breaking everything in that object because you put everything in the trigger.

The trigger should pass the objects to separate methods of a different class depending on the situation (update, insert, etc). This means you can add functionality or update existing functionality without worrying about breaking unrelated logic.

The error is with your query - you can't reference fields you haven't pulled on the same object in your query (ex. date_start__c >=: hr__c.date_start__c). You have to pull/query the records, then do any comparison logic in another for loop.

This brings the next question/issue - are you planning on always checking every single record for duplicates? I don't see any field that mentions name to separate date overlap between different users? Is there no distinguishable field on these hr records (ex. EmployeeId?)? You can't do this without some type of identifier to understand what hr records are related to what drivers/users.

Below is an example assuming you have a field that lets you know who it belongs to (employeeId).

```
 trigger hrTrigger on hr__c (before insert, before update) {
    HrTriggerHandler hrHandler = new HrTriggerHandler();
    if(trigger.isInsert){
       hrHandler.checkDateConflicts(Trigger.new);
    }

    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
       hrHandler.checkDateConflicts(Trigger.new);
    }
}
```

```
public class HrTriggerHandler {
    public static void checkDateConflicts(List<hr__c> hrRecs){
        List<Id> hrEmpIds = new List<Id>();
        for(hr__c hr : hrRecs){
            hrEmpIds .add(hr.EmployeeId);
        }
       //query all existing records related to the users who are creating new hr 
        records
        List<hr__c> personnel = [SELECT Id,date_end__c,date_start__c FROM hr__c WHERE 
        status__c = 'approved' AND employeeId IN : hrEmpIds ];

        for(hr__c hrCheck : personnel){ 
            //do logic here to check any date overlap between personnel and what existed 
            in the trigger with hrrecs).
        }
    }
}
```